# Cite letter and article separately even though both are on the same webpage?

Tags: citations, academic-writing, non-fiction, chicago-manual-of-style

I am writing a formal research paper (for a competition called National History Day), using the Chicago citation style.

I am using as a source [this article](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/nasa%E2%80%99s-early-stand-women-astronauts-%E2%80%9Cno-present-plans-include-women-space-flights%E2%80%9D). I would like to quote/reference the letter pictured in the article, and also reference some of the article surrounding it.
I must sort my sources as primary or secondary. Which is this article? (I know the letter is a primary source.) Also, should I cite the letter and the article separately, or together?

Thanks; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter is a primary source, as you already know.  This is the *actual artifact*, the letter the young woman received from NASA.

The article about the history of these events is a secondary source; it's not a record of the events itself but a description.  (It might actually be a tertiary source, but you could make the case for secondary.)  [This article](http://tuskegee.libguides.com/c.php?g=546110&p=3780244) explains more about primary, secondary, and tertiary sources.  It's not part of CMOS but appears to be from a university that uses CMOS as its standard.

If you are using the article only to provide access to the letter, then you cite the letter while crediting the publication:

> Lloyd, Jr., O. B., O. B. Lloyd, Jr. to Linda Halpern, March 13, 1962, in [... cite article here]

See "a letter found on a website" in [these Chicago citation guidelines](http://library.menloschool.org/chicago/letter).

If you are also using the article in other ways, and not just as your source for the letter, then cite the article itself where you use it.

Comment: So, cite the article where it is used, and cite the letter within the article where it is used. Fabulous explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I noticed while tagging my question that there were no [tag:primary-source] or [tag:secondary-source] tags - maybe these should be added?

Comment: @heather thanks for mentioning the tags, which I hadn't looked closely at.  I made some changes there.  I *think* that primary/secondary sources would be covered under [tag:academic-writing], but please feel free to make a proposal on meta if you think this idea should be called out with a separate tag.  Thanks, and I'm glad my answer helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! That makes sense that it's covered by academic writing.